New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject parameter broke
I was trying to use the method New-SelfSignedCertificate. Let say that I've used the example call from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps
$params = @{
    Type = 'Custom'
    Subject = 'E=patti.fuller@contoso.com,CN=Patti Fuller'
    TextExtension = @(
        '2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4',
        '2.5.29.17={text}email=patti.fuller@contoso.com&upn=pattifuller@contoso.com' )
    KeyAlgorithm = 'RSA'
    KeyLength = 2048
    SmimeCapabilities = $true
    CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My'
}
New-SelfSignedCertificate @params

First I've got this error:
New-SelfSignedCertificate : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'Subject' is ambiguous. Possible
matches include: -SubjectName -SubjectAlternative.

And I've changed Subject to SubjectName resulting:
New-SelfSignedCertificate : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubjectName'. The argument "E=patti.fuller@contoso.com,CN=Patti Fuller"
does not match the "^(CN|E|O|OU|C|ST|L):[^,:]+$" pattern. Supply an argument that matches "^(CN|E|O|OU|C|ST|L):[^,:]+$"
and try the command again.

Which actually matching the pattern. I've run similar command also few days ago and it worked correctly. I am using Windows 11

I'm getting the same error did you find a solution?

Nope. I found out that some people with slightly different windows settings have possibility to run this. For me workaround was using VM. Didn't found the root cause...

I had the same error, and for me it was caused by another module "OpenSSL" which was interfering with the PKI module from Microsoft.
The conflict can be solved by uninstalling the "OpenSSL" module or removing it from the session and importing the pki module instead.
Remove-Module "OpenSSL"
Import-Module "pki"

